# execution with argument

Tags: bash, xargs

I am using below xargs command to execute parallel on all the hosts (without arguments) where file.txt contains hosts.

```
xar-n 1 -P 500 SCRIPT_PATHt
```

Below is the way to execute a script (with argument) on one host

```
SCRIPT_PATH host1
```

Now my requirement is to execute a script with arguments on multiple hosts via xarg command parallelly.
Tried below, but didn't work. Is it possible to be done via xargs ?

```
xargs -n 1 -P 500 SCRIPT_PATH "
```

Comment: 1. `Tried below, but didn't work` - what does it mean "didn't work"? Did it execute incorrectly, execute something else, exit with non-zero exit status, print something you didn't like, took to long, spill your coffee? Note there is a helpful `-t` option with `xargs`. 2. `on multiple hosts` - is this misleading? The script itself is executing on a single machine, you just want the arguments to change, right? 3. `/SCRIPT_PATH` - you didn't specify the `/` in front of the `SCRIPT_PATH` in `xargs`, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## xargs solution: `-I` argument

There is an [-I option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#-I_option) for xargs:

> The xargs command offers options to insert the listed arguments at some position other than the end of the command line. The -I option to xargs takes a string that will be replaced with the supplied input before the command is executed. A common choice is %.

In your case:

```sh
xargs -n 1 -P 500 -I % SCRIPT_PATH % "arguments" < file.txt # % as input line
xargs -n 1 -P 500 -I {} SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments" < file.txt # {} as input line
```

## GNU parallel solution

[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#NAME) - just like `xargs`, but more powerful & convenient.

> parallel - build and execute shell command lines from standard input in parallel

### Piping input to `parallel`

Your script can be used with `parallel` just like with `xargs`:

```sh
parallel -n 1 -P 500 -I {} SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments" < file.txt # just replace xargs with parallel
parallel -P 500 SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments" < file.txt # you can omit -n 1 -I arg
```

### `parallel` using `--argfile` argument

You can set input file `file.txt` as argument instead of piping it contents. It may be helpful if you want use `STDIN` of script for other purposes.

```sh
parallel -P 500 --arg-file file.txt SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments"  # --arg-file argument
parallel -P 500 -a file.txt SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments"  # -a is an --arg-file synonym
parallel -P 500 SCRIPT_PATH {} "arguments" :::: file.txt # '::::' - another way to write -a argfile1
```

### `parallel` execute scripts remotely using `--sshloginfile`

You can manage script execution on remote hosts directly from `parallel` using `--sshloginfile` or `-slf`

```sh
parallel -P 500 --slf file.txt --nonall SCRIPT_PATH "arguments"
```

Comment: How to re-direct any output if there is any to null ? I am using --> " xargs -n 1 -P 500 -I % SCRIPT_PATH % "arguments" < file.txt  "

Comment: @Sin15 try `xargs -n 1 -P 500 -I % SCRIPT_PATH % "arguments" < file.txt > /dev/null`